# How can I make a function that increases the total supply of a token every 365 days?

Tags: solidity, remix

Does anybody know a simple function that can increase the total token supply every 365 days with solidity?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a "scheduled job" on ethereum - someone have to sign the transactions.
So you need to find a different pattern.

I would think about a function which would issue tokens on calll and record in state when the last issuance happened.

so it would allow only new issuance according to your rules.

Depending on your specific requirements it might be possible to make this fx trustless, ie. anyone could call and it would issue new tokens to a preset address or whatever is your rule.

If its trustless then you can also think about reward the caller so ppl would be incentified to call the function. (ethereum alarm clock is a generic  example of this idea but im not sure of the project status)

Also you can have a look for oraclize.it. There you can request a callback in a given time and you can setup the next call on the callback.

but if you can make it trustless and rewarded then no need to rely on any external party so that its more robust and sustainable.